# Best way to access CSS Variable in custom Directive of angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have one question about.. How can we convert below statement to angular`s renderer2 ?

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.setProperty( '--primary-color ' , '#455363' )
```

Above statement is changing css-variable into the directive when dark mode is selected. As in angular it is not good practice to access DOM directly, thats why we uses renderer2. But i do not know how to convert above statement to renderer2 for safely access DOM.

At very simple, can anyone tell me how to safely change css-varible in directive using renderer2 or best way to get css-variable into directive.

Thanks you.

Comment: just a suggestion, don't change the css variables with angular. set style and change the style name. it's easier to style the component. you can even enable theming. this is not consider as a good approach

Comment: @MoHradA Can you give one example link on theming? And can you provide more details on how it is not good practice to change css variables with angular ?

Comment: check https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/design-system/create-custom-theme#create-custom-theme

it's all done through mixin and functions and a single service

Comment: @MoHradA Thank you for your suggestion!! What I am going to achieve is bit of like this similar approach but different way. You can check out my little implementation in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5k9xl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.ts

Comment: @MoHradA In my way I am using Directive. We can place this directive as parent wrapper. One service for theme-change. and Let user will decide how they uses this directive and service. What they need to do is First, Define their own variable color scheme, then they need to pass that color scheme to service method `changeTheme()` .

Comment: buy why they need to do that when they can do it easily with css? directive isn't over engineering it? and even your directive could apply an additional css to the element

Answer (score 9):

As I have gone through more details about `setStyle()` of `renderer2` there are total Four parameters we can pass on it.

```
/**
    * Implement this callback to set a CSS style for an element in the DOM.
    * @param el The element.
    * @param style The name of the style.
    * @param value The new value.
    * @param flags Flags for style variations. No flags are set by default. enum: 1 or 2, 
      1: Marks a style as important.   
      2: Marks a style as using dash case naming (this-is-dash-case).
*/

abstract setStyle(el: any, style: string, value: any, flags?: RendererStyleFlags2): void;
```

Now we can pass fourth parameter `2` , that will helps to define css-variable with `-` style variable, without `2` parameter `setStyle()` will not recognize cas-variable. So this is actual my answer to my question..

```
`this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, `--primary-color`, '#455363' , 2 )`
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding 2 its better to use the RendererStyleFlags2 symbolic constants: `this.renderer.setStyle(nativeElement, '--primary-color', '#455363' ,  RendererStyleFlags2.DashCase)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something along these lines:

```js
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.renderer.setStyle(
    this.elementRef.nativeElement,
    '--primary-color',
    '#455363'
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Since setStyle() doesn't recognize `--primary-color` CSS variable.

Comment: I'm not sure, no, I haven't tried adding styles this way, but does it throw an error?

Comment: `--primary-color` isn't a proper css property so angular won't add any style using `setStyle()`.

Comment: Checkout my findings answer on `setStyle()`, we have to pass fourth parameter for accessing css-variable with `-` style.

Comment: Excellent finding! Have upvoted your answer, will delete mine in a few hours so you can see this message first ^^

Answer (score 0):

from your question I guess that you want to enable theming, so here is solution which isn't related directly to your question but give you a better insight on how this could be worked out

```
.theme1{
  --primary-color: red;
}

.theme2{
  --primary-color: blue;
}

// inside component1
:host{
   background-color : var(--primary-color);
}

//inside the AppComponent 
<body[class]="isTheme1? 'theme1': 'theme2'">
 <component1></component1>
</body>
```

to explain it. each css variable is scoped to its style. meaning if style1 is applied to the component or parent, then the value that is available inside that component will read from the parent/self element

```
<!-- scoped to the body-->
<bod class="theme1">
    <div>
        <component1> </component1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <component1> </component1>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- scoped to parent div -->
<bod >
    <div class="theme1">
        <component1> </component1>
    </div>
    <div class="theme2">
        <component1> </component1>
    </div>
</body>

<!-- scoped to the component and mix and match  -->
<bod class="theme1">
    <div>
        <component1> </component1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <component1 class="theme2"> </component1>
    </div>
</body>
```

so with above code, your component will have two different color side by side. you probably don't want to do mix and match, but I kept this here to show that the scope of variable is based on the parent/self element.

[nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/design-system/create-custom-theme#tweak-backgrounds) is doing it more professionally but it's the whole idea